# OR-Tools: Ensure group of nodes is visited by vehicles from the same depot

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I would like to use OR-Tools to solve a CVRP where each node has a label, and all the nodes that have the same label have to be visited by vehicles that originate from the same starting location. It does not matter which this starting location is, the only requirement is that it is the same for all the nodes with the same label. Is there a way to model this using the routing library?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of "SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex" method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).